# Change boolean values on listviewitems in firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-listview

How can I change my boolean value in firebase when clicking on a listview item?

My `setOnItemClick` in my MainActivity:

```
listitem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        }
    });
```

Adapter:

```
public class listItems extends ArrayAdapter<Items> {

private Activity context;
private List<Items> listitems;



public listItems(Activity context, List<Items> listitems){
    super (context, R.layout.list_items, listitems);
    this.context = context;
    this.listitems = listitems;

}
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();


    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null, true);

    CheckedTextView tvitems = (CheckedTextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.fetch_image_title);



    Items items = listitems.get(position);

    tvitems.setText(items.getItemname());

    tvitems.setChecked(items.isChecked);




    return listViewItem;
}
```

If I change the value in `Firebase` it also changes in my application (from true to false), so that works. But how can I do the same in my application when I click on one item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `onItemClick()` method, add the following lines of code:

```
String key = arrayAdapter.getItem(i).getKey();
yourRef.child(key).setValue(true);
```

This is the example for setting `true`. If you want to set it to `false`, please use:

```
yourRef.child(key).setValue(false);
```

Comment: Hi, It seems that I can not put that code in my MainActivity. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: You should not put in the MainActivity but in your `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` method, right?

Comment: My `onItemClick` is in my MainActiviy. Here is the code: `listitem.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String key = arrayAdapter.getItem(position).getKey();
                databaseItems.child(key).setValue(true);`

Comment: And `arrayAdapter` is red.

Comment: How do you instantiate your adapter object? You should change `arrayAdapter` with the name of your adapter.

Comment: I'm new to this, but I believe my adapter is this: ` ArrayAdapter<Items>`

Comment: How youcreate a new object of your adapter class?

Comment: Do mean how I add a new item in my listview?

Comment: No, how you create a new object of your `listItems` class?

Comment: I got it to work now :)  I added this:                                                                                     `Items items = listitem.get(position);
                String key = items.getItemId();`

Comment: Good to hear that :)

Comment: No problem, Thank you for your help!